# Jquery, Validate, Submit Form to PHP (Ajax Problem)

Tags: forms, jquery, jquery-validate

Very early days playing Javascript, Jquery and Validate.

I am using the Submit Button onClick method for form submission.

```
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="submitForm()" />
```

I am using the submit, in case no data or not every field has been tested.

The logic is working, but the AJAX call does not appear to be working.  I have stripped down the PHP to

```
<?php

touch('phpTouch.txt');
phpinfo();
sleep(30;)
?>
```

The javascript is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#formEnquiry').validate();
});

function submitForm() {
    $('#msgid').append('<h1>Submitting Form (External Routine)</h1>');
    if ($('#formEnquiry').validate().form() ) {
        $("#msgid").append("<h1>(Outside Ready) VALIDATED send to PHP</h1>");
            $.ajax({
            url: "testPHP.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: frmData,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function () {
                alert("SUCCESS:");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("ERROR: ");
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('#msgid').append('<h1>(Outside Ready) NOT VALIDATED</h1>');
    }
    return false;  // Prevent the default SUBMIT function occurring (is this a fact ??)
};
```

Can anyone advise as to what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Few things come to mind. First there should be a submithandler in the validate. So this would be an option inside the validate function. Second i wouldn't put a function inside the onclick. If you want a handler and you are using jquery you should use the event handlers in jquery such as `$(".submit").click(..);` but in this case you shouldn't even need that, just the submitHandler on validate. Also there is .submit() is jquery.

Comment: The problem I have is my knowledge is so small, I do not understand about built in handlers.  I know how to program (although syntax for a new language eg javascript is a learning curve), but do each step one at a time, where I can understand what is going on.  I was advised to use the sublit in Validate, but it seemed to be being executed, with an empty form and so I adapted this step at a time approach and I am obviously doing something wrong, because the php file is not being executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do these things

Change <strike>`onClick="submitForm()"`</strike> on the HTML markup to `onclick="submitForm(event)"`
Now change the `submitForm` function like this.

```
function submitForm(evt) {
    $('#msgid').append('<h1>Submitting Form (External Routine)</h1>');
    if ($('#formEnquiry').valid() ) {
        $("#msgid").append("<h1>(Outside Ready) VALIDATED send to PHP</h1>");
            $.ajax({
            url: "testPHP.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: frmData,
            contentType: "application/json;",
            success: function () {
                alert("SUCCESS:");
            },
            error: function (a, b, c) {
                alert(a.statusText);
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('#msgid').append('<h1>(Outside Ready) NOT VALIDATED</h1>');
    }
    evt.preventDefault();
};
```

Please note these things

1. Check `.valid()` to determine form validity
2. Call `.preventDefault()` instead of `return false;` ( Its more jQuery-ish )

Comment: Many Thanks.  The problem is still there.  I have checked permissions on php file and it does update the file's time with the `touch` test.  Something is happening in the background, because the messages in 'submitForm(event) are not shown and the screen refreshes and clears the data in the form fields.  Sorry it did not work, but I have learnt a bit more.

Comment: If I make the form action the name of the php file, the php file executes, so somehow the AJAX is just not executing.  I wish I understood more about the underlying chain of events and then I could somehow try to debug them.

Comment: are yoiu getting any error? i ahve updated code. also tell me what is inside the variable frmData? is it valid json? could you show me that? also alert and check whether you are getting inside the valid part. also make the input type="button"

Comment: Many thanks again for helping.  I do not get any error messages I am aware of !!.  'frmData is something I copied from an example.  My method in the form is POST and I did not know what to put in `data:` or whether it was needed.  I would like to get back from the php some JSON if there are errors and the email was not sent. I have pressed on with the PHP and it is receiving all the data and sending the email, but it only works via the Action in form and I would still like to use AJAX and hopefully understand how it works.  Could my ISP block the AJAX ?   Thanks again - much appreciated.

Comment: @mcl no, if you can post a normal post then ajax is just an additional step so it doesn't refresh the page. Can you edit your post and put a link to the validate plugin you are using. There are quite a few out there, i just want to make sure you are using the one I'm thinking of and i can give you an example. Also @ me when you do so saying it's been edited so i know to check it out.

Comment: @Matt.  I am making progress I have changed data: to `data: $('#formEnquiry').serialize(),` and it is working.  So the problem was frmData. Be wary of copying code when you are only seeing a snippet.  I thought it was some magical inbuilt variable. @Naveen. Thanks it was your comment that made me investigate 'frmData' further.  It works OK whether I use `type=Button or type=Submit`.

Comment: @Matt, Naveen or anyone.  I am now having trouble getting my head around the return from AJAX.  It is coming back as an ERROR, but it has successfully sent the email.  What is the correct return procedure.  I would like to receive some JSON messages along with the appropriate flag to set to activate either a success: or an error:  Thanks

Comment: @mcl you should make a new question, but you can try setting dataType. This is an option in .ajax. Set it to json. It may think it's not valid xhtml or something depending on how you are returning it. If this doesn't work then go ahead and create a new question with the updated code you have working so far.

Comment: @Matt Thanks for help also Naveen, I have now made a new question.